# ruby on rails , sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected QUOTED_STRING, expecting CONST_INT or '-' near ''5') AND `active` IN ('1') AND ....

Tags: sql, thinking-sphinx, ruby-on-rails-5

I use sphinx 3.4.0 and rails 5, when i want to search i got this error !!

```
sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected QUOTED_STRING, expecting CONST_INT or '-' near ''5') AND `active` IN ('1') AND ....
```

## index

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :firm, with: :active_record do

# fields
indexes corporate_name, :sortable => true, :as => :rs
indexes [addresses.city.region.name, addresses.free_region], :as => :wilaya
indexes [addresses.street_1, addresses.street_2, addresses.street_3], :as => :adresse
end
```

Comment: Can you share the search you're running that brings up this error?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're passing in a string in your search request - perhaps as a filter value? - when it should be an integer. Thinking Sphinx requires filter values to be cast as their appropriate types.

e.g.

```
Firm.search "foo", :with => {:account_id => params[:account_id].to_i}
```

This is a relatively recent change, so old documentation and examples may be out-of-date and not do this.